# How to add a timestamp to bash script log for every command and exclude set, echo, log?

Tags: linux, bash, logging

How to add a timestamp to bash script log for every command (exclude set, echo, log) ?

Im running a backup script and want to log all commands with timestamp:

```
 #./svnbackup.sh 2&>1 | timestamp_xtrace > ./svn-backup.log 2>&1
```

this is my function, which doesnt work:

```
 timestamp_xtrace() {
   while IFS= read -r line; do
     if [[ "$line" =~ "^+ set" ]] && [[ "$line" =~ "^+ echo" ]] && [[ "$line" =~ "^+ log" ]]; then
         echo "$(date) $line";
     fi
   done
 }
```

i want to exclude some commands (set, echo , log...)  but it doesnt work..
does someone have a hint to solve my problem?

Comment: Shouldn't those `&&`s be `||`s?

Comment: I suggest to use `logger`.

Comment: I want to log all lines but the lines starts with "set" or "echo" or "log".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working solution:

```
timestamp_xtrace() {
   while IFS= read -r line; do
     if [[ "$line" != "+ set"* ]] && [[ "$line" != "+ echo"* ]] && [[ "$line" != "+ log"* ]]; then
       echo "$(date) $line";
     fi
   done
}
```

i changed the regex (`=~ "^ "+ echo"`) to (`!= "+ echo"*`) so the test is matches the right lines :

```
# cat << EOF | timestamp_xtrace
+ somecmd
+ echo "hello world!"
hello world!
+ svnadmin -args
EOF
```

Output:

```
Wed Sep 30 09:12:43 CEST 2015 + somecmd
Wed Sep 30 09:12:43 CEST 2015 hello world!
Wed Sep 30 09:12:43 CEST 2015 + svnadmin -args
```

Answer (score 0):

This bash function should do the job:

```
timestamp_xtrace() { 
   while IFS= read -r line; do
      [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:blank:]]*(set|echo|log) ]] && echo "$(date):: $line"
   done
}
```

`^[[:blank:]]*(set|echo|log)` will match `set` OR `echo` OR `log` at start of line optionally preceded by space or tab.

**Testing:**

```
cat << EOF | timestamp_xtrace
foo bar
log something testing
echo and more
abc xyz
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Sep 29 10:40:44 EDT 2015:: log something testing
Tue Sep 29 10:40:44 EDT 2015:: echo and more
```

Comment: Yes true but OP's function was also printing it on stdout.